# Can't read file charset utf-16le except puts in ruby

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, ruby-csv

I need to read an external file in ruby.
Running `file -i` locally shows
`text/plain; charset=utf-16le`

I open it in ruby CSV with separater '\t' and a row shows as:
`<CSV::Row "\xFF\xFEC\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00i\x00d\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00n\x00u\`...

row.to_s produces `\x000\x000\x000\x001\x00\t\x00E\x00D\x00O`

Running `puts row` shows the data correctly:
`0001    EDOARDO A`...
(the values also show legibly in vim and LibreOffice Calc)

Any suggestions how to get the data in ruby? I've tried various combinations of opening the CSV with `external_encoding: 'utf-16le', internal_encoding: "utf-8"` etc., but `puts` is the only thing that gives legible values

It also said ASCII-8BIT in ruby CSV.
`<#CSV io_type:StringIO encoding:ASCII-8BIT lineno:0 col_sep:"\\t" row_sep:"\n" quote_char:"\"" headers:true>`

The file itself was produced as an XLS file. I have uploaded an edited version [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/eacecc6yvd0p3dc/part_of_file.xls/file) (edited i gvim)

Comment: Can you share the file or part of the file? Also the version of ruby you're using.

Comment: Could you provide you code also?

Comment: `col_sep:"\\t" row_sep:"\n"` looks strange. Do you really have '\t' separator, not _tabulation_ one?

Comment: I have added a link to an uploaded file now.
I am not sure what the column separator is, \t is a guess. (vim doesn't show a character code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was reading from a Paperclip attachment, which needed to have the encoding set (overridden) before saving.

Adding s3_headers in the model worked:

```
 has_attached_file :attachment, s3_headers: lambda { |attachment|
                                  { 
                                    'content-Type' => 'text/csv; charset=utf-16le'
                                  }
                                }
```

Thanks to Julien for tipping me off that the issue was related to the paperclip attachment (that solution works to read the file directly)

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine for me:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("file.xls", encoding: "UTF-16LE:UTF-8", col_sep: "\t") do |row|
  puts row.inspect
end
```

this will produce the following output:

```
["﻿Candidate number", "First name", "Last name", "Date of birth", "Preparation centre", "Result", "Score", "Reading and Writing", "Listening", "Speaking", "Result enquiry", "Raised on", "Raised by", "Enquiry status", "Withdrawn on", "Withdrawn by", nil]
["0001", "EDOARDO", "AGNEW", "20/01/2001", "Fondazione Istituto Massimo", "RY5-G8-Y2", "-", nil, nil, nil, "-", "00000000", nil, nil, "00000000", nil, nil]
```

As you can see each row is an array of strings of each column in the document.

Comment: Yes that works, I realise now the problem arises when the file is saved as a Paperclip attachment. Setting the encoding when reading the Paperclip attachment doesn't seem to work, so I am investigating how to set the encoding at the time of saving as an attachment